# Динамическое добавление элементов WindowsForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, form, формы

Как добавить динамически сразу несколько radioButton на форму по нажатию кнопки?
Вот что есть, но добавляется только по одному на каждый tabPage.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Quest " + i);
        tabControl1.SelectTab(i);

        if (comboBox1.Text == "One right answer")
        {
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.Width = 270;
            panel.Height = 280;
            panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 10);
            panel.Visible = true;
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(panel);
            panel.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;

            RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[4];
            for (byte count = 0; count < rb.Length; count++)
            {
                rb[count] = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
                rb[count].Width = 70;
                rb[count].Visible = true;
                rb[count].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 10 + i * 20);
                rb[count].Text = textBox2.Text;
                panel.Controls.Add(rb[count]);                    
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: `rb[count].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 10 + i * 20);` ===> `rb[count].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 10 + count * 20);`

Comment: @tym32167: Спасибо больше - помогло. Можете подсказать почему именно от этого зависело? Это же просто расположение.

Comment: вы до этого рисовали 4 радиобаттона один поверх другого, поэтому думали, что он один. Я просто подсказал, как рисовать их рядом друг с другом.

Comment: @tym32167: Спасибо, понял. Дошло - увеличиваю же i в конце...

Comment: Вместо простой панели можно взять `TableLayoutPanel` или `FlowLayoutPanel` - в них не нужно задавать местоположение вложенных контролов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы рисуете 4 радиобаттона один поверх другого, поэтому думаете, что он один. Вот так можно рисовать их рядом друг с другом.

Было:

```
rb[count].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 10 + i * 20);
```

Стало:

```
rb[count].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 10 + count * 20);
```